# GNOME 2 does not start in Ubuntu Linux 12.04 after login though installation is complete

Tags: unity, gnome, dual-boot, default

I have a pc with only 512 mb RAM. Ubuntu Linux has installed successfully. Instead of the default Unity desktop I need to use the GNOME desktop. I have done the installation of the desktop and logged out. However, after logging in , the desktop is the Unity interface. What do I need to do to use GNOME 2 successfully. Please give a step by step solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Try the solutions for 12.04 from this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic-desktop. If you have further issues please [edit] your question to include exact steps you took, and issues you have.

Answer (score 0):

In the login screen, click the Ubuntu icon next to your name.

[image: Login]

Next, select Gnome 2 as your environment. I do not have Gnome 2, but you should see it on your menu

[image: Select enviroment]

After that, Click `Back`, Enter your password, and that should do it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However the Ubuntu icon you have mentioned should appear, does not appear at all. All that appears is the Login name and password. Can anyone tell me why this happens. All steps given for installation of Gnome 2 on ubuntu forum have been done.